# Why alpha in KKT condition has to greater than or equal to zero

Tags: svm

When I read SVM, I got quite confused by KKT condition, I wonder why it set the alpha >=0, my guess is that since constraint is g(x)<=0, if alpha < 0, then maximizing has no meaning, just set alpha = -Inf. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a late answer but I am putting my understanding here for other visitors.

α>=0 is the constraint that you get when you convert a primal problem into its corresponding dual problem. Even if you put aside KKT conditions for a moment and convert a primal optimisation problem into a dual problem, it will be required that α>=0. I suggest you go through the theory of convex optimization and lagrange multipliers in details to get the concept clear.